# Me aparece el siguiente error: iloc cannot enlarge its target object

Tags: python, pandas

Estoy recién empezando con python y estoy realizando este código (el código es enorme y no puedo exponerlo completamente, solo puedo mostrar esta parte)

```
    cols = -1
    fils = 0
    fils1 = 100
    for i in range(int(((len(list1))/2))):
      cols = cols + 1
      if cols <= col-1:
        df.iloc[fils1,cols] = df.iloc[fils,cols] - mdl.sum(df2.iloc[i,j]*(x[eval(arcos1[j])].solution_value) for j in range(len(list21)))
      else:
        fils = fils + 1
        fils1 = fils1 + 1
        cols = 0
        df.iloc[fils1,cols] = df.iloc[fils,cols] - mdl.sum(df2.iloc[i,j]*(x[eval(arcos1[j])].solution_value) for j in range(len(list21)))
```

En la fila 7, luego del if, me aparece este error (IndexError: iloc cannot enlarge its target object )

Datos extras:

-El código me funciona perfectamente, salvo esa línea, el error estoy seguro que es el fils1, pero no entiendo porque no funciona con fils1 y si funciona a la perfección con fils.

-Básicamente estoy tomando un dataframe con 86 filas y necesito realizar este calculo de mi optimización desde la fila 100 y exponer desde allí los resultados.

-Asumo que estoy usando .iloc de forma inadecuada, pero, investigue, y no se me ocurre que otra puedo utilizar, utilizaría .loc, pero no puedo trabajar con etiquetas. Y, eso, muchas gracias a todos de antemano!

-La razón por la que no utilizo fils es porque me borra las filas anteriores y no quiero eso, y como lo resuelve bien hasta que cambio de fils a fils1 se que ahí esta el problema.
De antemano muchas gracias!!

Comment: Aqui hay una pregunta relacionada de SO en inglés https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64139881/pandas-error-indexerror-iloc-cannot-enlarge-its-target-object

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: **Nota:** Al utilizar `pandas` es recomendable no utilizar ciclos (Por ejemplo `for`) para iterar en los elementos, hay métodos optimizados que trabajan con el `dataset` rápida y eficientemente. En la mayoría de los casos, si lo que quieres hacer crees que se puede hacer con un `for` entonces es el camino incorrecto (O el que va a tardar más y tener mayor impacto al procesador). En esos casos, si no hay un método directo que realice la tarea entonces apply podría ser una buena opción, como último recurso sería utilizar ciclos. Sin ver los datos y el código es difícil adivinar el problema.